# Query my database on AWS over an SSH tunnel with Pandas

Tags: mysql, pandas, amazon-web-services

I am trying to query to my database running on AWS over an SSH tunnel with Pandas. But I fail login. Also there is one key that I use to connect on SQL client (Sequel Pro) that I don't know how to use in my python code.

This is the key: `heroes-us-west-1-master.cheme3bzdejb.us-west-1.rds.amazonaws.com`

This is my code:

```
     with SSHTunnelForwarder(
          (host, 22),
          ssh_username=ssh_username,
          ssh_private_key=ssh_private_key,
          remote_bind_address=(localhost, 3306)
     ) as server:
          conn = db.connect(host=localhost,
          port=server.local_bind_port,
          user=user,
          passwd=password,
          db=database)
          return pd.read_sql_query(q, conn)

df = query("SELECT stores.name, stores.address\
    FROM stores;")
```

This is the error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "connection.py", line 32, in <module>
    FROM stores;")
  File "connection.py", line 22, in query
    remote_bind_address=(localhost, 3306)
  File "/Users/Solal/Desktop/SQL/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sshtunnel.py", line 904, in __init__
    logger=self.logger
  File "/Users/Solal/Desktop/SQL/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sshtunnel.py", line 1095, in _consolidate_auth
    raise ValueError('No password or public key available!')
ValueError: No password or public key available!
```

Comment: your private key seems wrong. Check `ssh_private_key` and also for the db.connect, the host should be what you wrote not the localhost I think.

Comment: I checked my private key on Sequel Pro and I can successfully login